# How to keep service running in background when app is closed but stop/disable it when the app is in foreground?

Tags: java, android

I am having difficulties trying to handle service behaviour in such case.

Basically I have a service running on a separate process that needs to issue httprequests every certain time whenever the app is closed, then write something into preferences or throw a notification.

The logic works fine. The problem I'm having is that **I cannot find a way to properly stop/disable that service whenever the app is running, aswell as start it again when the app is being finished or put into background**.

I've tried stopping it at @onResume()/@onStart() callbacks of my activities aswell as starting it at @onStop()/@onDestroy() but behaviour doesnt run as expected in any case...

I'll paste here some code snippets of what i've tried so far:

I start/stop services using:

```
stopService(new Intent(this,NotificationService.class));
startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));
```

Random activity from my app (all implement this in their callbacks):

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        if (Utility.isMyServiceRunning(this)){
            Utility.serviceClose(this);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (!Utility.isMyServiceRunning(this)){
            startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

This somehow doesnt work or brings unexpected behaviour since the app moves from many activities, and service ends up being alive when the app is running or stopped when the app is in background/finished.

I've also tried to toggle on/off service logic on service timertask every cicle by asking:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {

       ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
                for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
                    if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.example.myapp")) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
    //service http request logic here
    }
```

But that doesnt work either because process "com.example.myapp" never gets killed (and of course I cannot/want to force finish that), so it never issues any httprequest.

Any Ideas on how to implement this? Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with better handling of onStop() onResume() callbacks.

Comment: Can you please tell how did you handle OnStop or OnResume...?

Answer (score 2):

How about binding to your service and then communicating directly with it?  Implement a simple on/off boolean, expose a getter/setter on the binding, and then make sure the service checks the boolean before it does any work.  That way you can disable it while the app is running without having to actually start/stop the service repeatedly.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I considered the option.

Comment: The problem is that im afraid this solution will suffer of the same issues. I cannot for instance click multi-task then drag the app away and expect the onDestroy() to be called so that I can unbind the service and/or toggle a boolean.

Comment: It is not so much about the way of communicating the service with the app or viceversa but about making sure that whenever the app is on background/finished the service will run its requests every x time. Aswell as whenever the app is started it shoudlnt.

Comment: One thing that could be causing issues with your current solution is that when switching Activities, `onResume()` is called on the new activity _before_ `onStop()` is called on the old one. That means your service will end up running when you switch activities. You should be able to see this easily by breakpointing the appropriate methods. As for why you might find it not running when the app is closed, perhaps the OS is closing it? If you want your service to run permanently, you'll want to use `startForeground()` instead.